# Json usage with vpn client Windscribe

Tags: java, parsing, proxy, jsoup, vpn

I am trying to connect to the website [https://www.sierra.com/] and parse page via VPN service Windscribe. But when trying to parse with active VPN service I get errors:

1. `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake`
2. `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`
3. `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`

I have tried to use the following commands with proxy, that I found on the Internet and and without:

```
 Document page = Jsoup.connect(URL).proxy("154.197.132.134", 3128)
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 
Safari/537.36").timeout(0).maxBodySize(0).execute().parse();


 Document page = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36").timeout(0).maxBodySize(0).execute().parse();
```

When I turn off VPN all works fine.

Comment: On using the command `curl -v https://www.sierra.com/`, I am getting the same kind of error  with VPN : `curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60`. Even without VPN, it's the same error.

Comment: But if you delete .proxy command you will see that all works fine!